# Display parent web part on Subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, web-part, data-view-web-part, sub-site

I am trying to create several master lists at the top level of a SharePoint Online site - master calendar, master contacts, etc.

I want to be able to display these lists on Subsites, but I'm running into an error. I've used SharePoint Designer 2013 to create a data view web part which I then save to the site gallery. But when I try to add the new web part on a subsite, I receive the following error:

> "The file you imported is not valid. Verify that the file is a Web
> Part description file (*.webpart or *.dwp) and that it contains
> well-formed XML."

What am I missing? I would very much appreciate any ideas! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To display parent web part on subsite, refer to the following article step by step:

https://blog.cloudbusiness.com/the-company/blog-and-news/displaying-sharepoint-online-2013-lists-to-parent-or-sub-sites

Comment: Thanks - this is the article I was originally using. It's a pretty simple process, so I'm not sure what could be going wrong. Still getting that error, though. Any other ideas?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this problem - any ideas what could be causing this error?